# whats the impact of using ob_get_clean without ob_start

Tags: php

I am using ob_get_clean in a script that is called by ajax

it stops junk being returned

i was using ob_start but it is a banned function for me

Taking ob_start() out of my code seems to make no difference to how it works

So as i'm only using ob_get_clean to stop junk being passed back is there any implications to not using ob_start?

Test Code:

```
test();
ob_get_clean(); 
print 'HELLO';

function test() {
print 'TEST';
}
```

As I wanted only HELLO prints

Comment: The docs seem to suggest that `ob_get_clean` will return false if `ob_start` hasn't been called. Are you certain that it makes no difference?

Comment: well it seams to stop any output which is what I was after - as you say manual suggest you need an ob_start which was why I was asking the question